# How is $\varepsilon_+^\mu(p) = \bar{v}(k) \gamma^\mu u(p)$ derived?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, gauge-invariance

The relation $$\varepsilon_+^\mu(p) = \bar{v}(k) \gamma^\mu u(p)$$ is sometimes used to ease calculations of Feynman amplitudes with external gluons (see for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0509223) at (2.13)). Where does this relation come from?

How can we use the above relation to show that
$$\varepsilon_+(p) \cdot \varepsilon_+(q) = 0 \,\, \forall p,q,$$
and can this last equation also be obtained throught some gauge transformation, without using the relation between polarization vectors and Dirac spinors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stumbled upon the spinor helicity formalism. The idea is as follows. Massless spinors have many useful relationships among them that we can use. Thus instead of using the polarization vector, $\epsilon_\mu$ or massive spinors lets just map these objects into massless spinors and then use the convenient relationships between them to simplify amplitudes.

In this particular case you are looking at a mapping for the polarization vector. By Lorentz invariance the expression, $A\bar{v} \gamma^\mu u $ is the simplest thing you can write down (I guess you could try a derivative instead of $\gamma_\mu$ but this might lead to problems down the road).

Since $\epsilon_\mu$ represents a massless gauge field it has 2 degrees of freedom, while $\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u $ has in 4 degrees of freedom. Therefore,  $v$ must not be a physical quantity. It just needs to be fixed when choosing a gauge.

With regards to your identity we have,
\begin{align}
\epsilon _\mu ^+ \cdot \epsilon ^{+ \mu } & = A ^2 \left\langle  p + | \gamma _\mu | k + \right\rangle  \left\langle  p + | \gamma ^\mu | k + \right\rangle  \\ 
& = A ^2 \left\langle  p + | \gamma _\mu | k + \right\rangle  \left\langle  k - | \gamma ^\mu p - \right\rangle  \\ 
& = 2A ^2 \left\langle  p + | p - \right\rangle  \left\langle  k - | k + \right\rangle \\
& = 0
\end{align} 
where we have used the massless spinor relations, $ \left\langle  A + | \gamma ^\mu | B + \right\rangle  = \left\langle  B - | \gamma ^\mu A - \right\rangle  $ and $ \left\langle  A + | A - \right\rangle  = 0 $. These are both easy to derive by returning to $u, \bar{u}$ notation and manipulating the spinors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about the possibility of using a gauge transformation to obtain $\varepsilon^+(p)\cdot \varepsilon^+(q) = 0 \forall p,q$ ? Is this possible? It is easy to achieve with to fixed $p$ and $q$, but having to make (for example) four of them orthogonal to each other seems to be harder.

Comment: I think so (though I'm not an expert so please let me know if you find out I'm wrong). Following the derivation above you could imagine a new reference momentum $k'$ on the second braket. Then you would end with with the braket, $\left\langle k - | k ' + \right\rangle$ which you can always set to zero by choosing your reference momenta such that,$k = k ' $. Then the braket vanishes and you still have the gauge freedom to set $k$ to be whatever you wish.